# EF - Code First: Problem saving values in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I'm trying to add a tagging system to a webapplication build on MVC3 with EF Code First for data access. The base is pretty simple. I have Projects, Companies and People who can have 1 or more tags. I do not want to save the tags for each entity alone, so the tag class has 3 ICollections: People, Companies and Projects. Each of the entities has an ICollection of tag. see the code below

```
public class Project 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> People { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

In the context the mapping is set like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
    .HasMany(t => t.Projects)
    .WithMany(p => p.Tags)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("ID");
        m.MapRightKey("TagID");
        m.ToTable("TagProjects");
    });


modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
    .HasMany(t => t.People)
    .WithMany(p => p.Tags)
    .Map(m => 
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("ID");
        m.MapRightKey("TagID");
        m.ToTable("TagPeople");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
    .HasMany(t => t.Companies)
    .WithMany(p => p.Tags)
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapLeftKey("ID");
        m.MapRightKey("TagID");
        m.ToTable("TagCompanies");
    });
```

Now when I try to add a tag to a project like this:

```
public void AddTagToProject(int tagId, int projectId)
{
    ProjectRepository projectRepository = new ProjectRepository();
    Project project = projectRepository.GetProjectByID(projectId);
    project.Tags.Add(GetTagByID(tagId));

    Save();
}
```

there is no exception, but the project has no tags added to it either. Anyone have an idea where to look ?

```
public Tag GetTagByID(int tagId) 
{ 
    return db.Tags
        .Where(t => t.TagID == tagId)
        .First(); 
}
```

**I've found the solution, the problem was that the project was not correctly updated and the values were never saved.**

Comment: and what GetTagByID function code looks like?

Comment: public Tag GetTagByID(int tagId)
    {
        return db.Tags.Where(t => t.TagID == tagId).First();
    }

Comment: Some extra info. The tag is created correctly on insert, but the jointable that has been created bij Code First is not filled. Any ideas why ? 

When I seed this table manually the project shows the correct tags. Do I have to set the values in the jointable myself?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure your database doesn't have any oddly named columns generated by EF 4.1? I had that happen once, and the FK column was called UserTrialLicense_UserTrialLicenseID. So anytime I tried to eager-load anything using .Include, it would not work.

Comment: I checked the db creation script and it creates three new unspecified tables all looking like this:

    create table [dbo].[TagProjects] (
    [ID] [int] not null,
    [TagID] [int] not null,
    primary key ([ID], [TagID])
);

Comment: That doesn't look right, you have two primary Keys ID and TagID? If ID should be your primary key then in your POCO you should decorate it with [Key]. IF - in your POCO you have two defined (ID and TagID) you should get rid of one. You are using Entity Framework 4.1 Codefirst correct? I just noticed how your Id's are setup, you may also want to try keeping a consistent scheme with all classes (ProjectID, TagID, PersonID, CompanyID) for your PKs.

Comment: In my understanding giving a class a public int ID makes that Code First generates this ID as primary key. For the TagProjects table it is correct that both fields are Primary Keys as this is a join table between to many-to-many related tables. 

The code works correctly now, the problem was in the fact that the entity the tag was related to (Project, company and person) was not updated after the tag was added, therefore there was nothing being saved in the jointable

Comment: Oh ya I forgot about that being a join table. So is it working now?